# How do you clone events and data to clone but apply to the newest clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

You can clone an element with it's events and data, but then the events still apply to the original object instead of the new object.

I have used jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/VZZG4/

To reproduce:
1. Hit the clone button
2. In the new text input, type "New"
3. Hit the new clone button
Actual result: The newest clone says "Test"
Expected result: The newest clone says "New"

Question: How do you clone events and data to clone but apply to the newest clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use closest() to clone the expected element...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clone').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('#container').clone(true).appendTo('#wrap');
    });
});
```

## [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/VZZG4/1/)

and I suggest for you to use `class` instead of an `id`. Duplicate `id` is not valid html.

Comment: Using closest() does seem to be the answer. Excuse the IDs, I hastily put together that test case. Anyway, this is all very well until you try to apply it to trovster's duplicate/remove jquery plugin... (http://www.trovster.com/lab/plugins/duplicate-remove/)

Answer (score 2):

You make the mistake to clone objects with IDs. In most browser, if you have several elements with the same ID, the first one will be returned. Thus `$('#container')` will always return the first one with the value `Test`.

Give the elements that should be cloned classes instead.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="edit" value="Test">
        <input type="button" class="clone" value="Clone">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clone').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.container').clone(true).appendTo('#wrap');
    });
});
```

Check the modified version  of your code http://jsfiddle.net/VZZG4/2/

**Reference:** [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)